# io_socket emit not working inside Express get request

Tags: node.js, express, socket.io

Dear stackoverflow users,
I lost all the afternoon trying to fix this issue with socket.emit.

The client (webpage) is able to connect to my server. I can clearly see the 'Socket connected' output on the Server terminal and also the socket.emit is working fine (I can see the "TEST" message inside the terminal of the web page).

What is not working is the socket.emit inside the app.get("/test_page" ...

what's wrong with my code? the io variable seems to have a global scope.

Below my app.js code

```
const express = require("express")
var http = require('http');
const socket_io = require('socket.io');

const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io=socket_io(server);

....

io.on('connection', (socket) => {
  console.log('Socket connected');
  io.emit("test","TEST"); //<-- this works fine
  socket.on('disconnect', () => {
    console.log('Socket disconnected');
  });
});

server.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/");
});

app.get("/test_page", async function(req, res){
  io.emit("test","TEST"); //<-- this does not work
  res.render("test_page.html")
})
```

below my index.html page script

```
const socket = io.connect()

socket.on('test', function(msg){
    console.log(msg)
});
```

Comment: The issue is that you're sending the message then instantly after sending an html file. You're likely not going to see the result of the socket emit and this is most likely the issue if you're not getting any errors.

Comment: @Ameer, it is correct. Many many thanks for your help. After I lot of time spent on the issue I lost the focus. Everything is working fine.
Again many thanks